Proxy pass error 404 Not Found nginx/1.25.3 with Docker and nginx conf template
I know this may seem like a duplicate, but I have tried many different configurations but I just can't get it to work! Basically here is my set-up.
nginx.conf.template:
upstream backend {
    server localhost:5003;
}

server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5003/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

Note the backslashes! Other answers say thats missing and why I may have issues but I made sure to have the backslashes, I have also tried different ways so backslash in /api/ but not in proxy_pass http://localhost:5003, and so on.. Nothing works :(
I also changed this file to hardcode some stuff, but earlier they were variables so thats why its a template conf file.
My dockerfile:
# Use the official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:18.19 AS build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Copy the entire application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the React app for production
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine

# Copy the built React app to Nginx's web server directory
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template

# Start Nginx when the container runs
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Docker compose file:
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

I spin up my docker container with:
docker-compose up --build -d
Also to verify everything is good I do docker exec frontend nginx -s reload and docker exec frontend nginx -T to see the exact config being used.
However, when I try to access localhost:3000/api/health then I get
404 Not Found
nginx/1.25.3

But if I instead bring up the frontend with npm run dev (which uses VITE), then localhost:3000/api/health works as expected!
Here is my working vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");

  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      react(),
      svgr({
        svgrOptions: {
          // svgr options
        },
      }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      exclude: ["js-big-decimal"],
    },
    test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: "jsdom",
    },
    server: {
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
      host: true,
      strictPort: true,
      port: env.FRONTEND_HTTP_PORT,
      proxy: {
        "/api": {
          target: env.BACKEND_SERVICE_URL,
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
};

The weird thing is, it works perfectly fine in my staging environment! If needed I can share exact config used there but my local config has drifted from that now as I have hacked my way to this state. Though one thing about the staging config that works is that I didn't have any backslashes, so it was location /api and proxy_pass also didn't have backslash at the end.

Your proxy_pass http://localhost:5003/; looks wrong. In a container, localhost is the container itself. So unless your Nginx container is also listening on port 5003, nothing is going to respond to the forwarded request.

Oh yes you're right. Is there a way around this? Normally the team uses npm run dev for development but still wanted to keep the nginx option.

Instead of proxy_pass http://localhost:5003, consider http://frontend:3000 and set Nginx and the frontend in the same network in the 'docker-compose.yml' file.
However, this configuration alone is not sufficient for a production environment, which requires additional settings. I would use shell scripts such as https://github.com/patternknife/docker-blue-green-runner.
